# using ajax jquery with ojects

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM seat WHERE type=$type AND seat=$seat";    
$getseats=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();    
echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,  'getseats'=>$getseats)); die;
```

this gives $getseats values in array.so i could do this:

```
success: function(response){
            var res=$.parseJSON(response);
            if(res.status == true)
            {
                var seat='';
                for(var i=0;  i<res.getseats.length;  i++) 
                {                    
                    seat += '<option value='+res.getseats[i].seat_id+'>'+res.getseats[i].seat+'</option>';
                    $('#seats').html(seat); 
                }
            }
```

but what if i use active record?

```
 $getseats=Seat::where(['type'=$type])->where(['seat'=>$seat])->all();    
 echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,  'getseats'=>$getseats)); die;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For activeRecord you should use (this return models)

```
$getseats=Seat::Find()->where(['type'=$type, 'seat'=>$seat])->all();   
echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,  'getseats'=>$getseats));
die;
```

if you want  the result like an array you can use

```
$getseats=Seat::Find()->where(['type'=$type, 'seat'=>$seat])->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: I mean the jquery part.

Comment: What do you mean? the jquery part should be the same using  ActiveRecord or createCommand  ..in my answer i have posted the right way for obtain the data using activeRecord ..  explain better ..

Comment: Ok. i have always wanted to use ActiveRecord. i guess `$getseats` here gives the object and `res.getseats[i].seat` will fail.

Comment: @micky   i have update the answer for asArray result